# Synchronizing Eclipse .classpath in code repository

Tags: eclipse, version-control, classpath

My team handles several Java projects using Eclipse, and shares the code using a code repository.

When a developer adds, removes or updates a `jar` file, the build is broken for everybody else, until they update their build path in Eclipse. This process involves cumbersome email synchronization.

For several reasons, we have decided not to commit the `.classpath` file to the repo. Instead, we came up with the following idea: Each project will have a committed file, say `jars.list`, which contains a list of `jar` files (and patterns). A script will convert this file into a local `.classpath` for eclipse. Whenever a developer changes its jars, it is his or her responsibility to change `jars.list` and commit it.

Is this a reasonable solution? Are there any existing solutions for this problem?

Comment: Checking .classpath and .project into source control is the intended approach - they're designed to do that. Why are you not doing that?

Comment: I'm afraid that there will be many conflicts due to personal configurations.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. The `.classpath` file is intended to be shared; you can keep it free from absolute paths through a variety of techniques, such as storing JARs in the project, having a separate "Libs" project, using Classpath Variables, etc. The bottom line is that chcking in `.classpath` is the intended way to do what you're trying to do with some elaborate, manual process.

Comment: @E-Riz Thanks. a. Do you know where can I find reference to the fact that `.classpath` is inteneded to be shared? b. Could you please post it as an answer? I would like to accept\upvote if it's the solution I pick.

Comment: I don't agree with E-Riz, commit IDE auto-generated files into version control is not a good practice, you can never guarantee that all developers within a team use exactly same development environment (same OS, same IDE, same JDK, or even same project folder path). if the number of jar files become tremendous, consider using Ant (with Ivy) or Maven manage jar dependencies, as an ultimate solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse `.project` and `.classpath` files are intended/designed to be checked into a version control repository (cvs, svn, git, etc). See [this page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_up_a_Java_project_to_share_in_a_repository%3F) in the Eclipse wiki.

There are various ways to keep the `.classpath` file "clean" (ie, free from absolute paths), which I mentioned in the Comments section above.

Comment: Looks like the right approach. The only problem is the JRE, which are manifested in the `.classpath` but are machine-specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371512/eclipse-classpath-in-svn-jre-collision

Comment: As one of the answers to that question points out, using an Execution Environment is the right way to specify the Java version that you want. Machine-specific JRE specifications are an historical remnant and really should be removed from the configuration options, IMO. Execution Environments are an abstraction above the physical JRE location that keeps your .classpath "clean" and portable.

Answer (score 2):

The build is broken because the absolute path to the JAR is different in each developer machine? If so, you could add a user variable to avoid the issue, this way each developer only have to configure one variable (like `LIB_DIR`):

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="LIB_DIR/path/to/file.jar"/>
```

There are other solutions. You could configure some user libraries in eclipse to group your JARs, and then export a `.userlibraries` file which could be shared in your repo. This way, there would be no absolute paths in `.classpath`, but they would be present in your `.userlibraries`.

You could also use some tool like Maven to manage dependencies on your project.

Anyway, I think you could share `.classpath` without problems...