# Eclipse .classpath in SVN: JRE collision

Tags: eclipse, version-control, metadata, eclipse-metadata

I'm about to commit Eclipse `.classpath` and `.project` into SVN, following the [good advice I got here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10340796/51197).

The problem is that some JRE definitions are unique to a developer's machine, e.g.:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="..JRE_CONTAINER/org..../Jeffs JRE"/>
```

If this line is committed, it fails on other machines that don't have `Jeffs JRE`.

Any idea for a workaround? Could the JRE definitions be shared as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never saw adding specific IDE configuration files as a good practice, but that's a different issue.

If you want to follow that path, you should use the variables.

Java Build Path > Add variable

Then you need to make sure that every single developer has those variables defined, everyone with their own paths.

(or use Maven to avoid these problems)

Comment: No variable is required for JRE. Execution Environments work as variable.

Answer (score 5):

In project properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Double click on you JRE and then choose: Use Execution Environments instead of Alternate JRE or Workspace default JRE. You .classpath entry will be then something like this:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
```

[image]